# Would this question fit Super User under Spotify tag?

Tags: discussion, support, migration

I asked [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87271/would-installing-different-versions-of-libssl-cause-problems), It's about Spotify, i think i have a better chance getting an answer on Unix & Linux website. But it's about Spotify and Super user has a tag for that. So i might be able to find a Spotify user who tried to run it on a Linux OS.

So is my question fit for Super User? And is it worth migrating it??

Because maybe and just maybe, the majority of Unix & Linux users have not used other than Linux for a long time, and Linux users rarely are interested in programs that run on Windows therefore, maybe and just maybe the majority of Unix & Linux don't know how to run Spotify on Linux.

But on Super User, you can find users that use all kind of OS, and users who like to dualboot, rather than use Linux only, thus i think there's a better chance of getting an answer here, though a Linux user is more likely to know about Linux packages like `libssl`, but a Linux user on the other hand is less likely to face the problem I'm facing, plus the fact that there are more active users on Superuser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question should be fine for Super User.

You kind of have 2 questions there though. One resulting from the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) approach. If you want to know how to get Spotify to run on a Debian release it wasn't intended for, then you should probably ask *that* and just note what you have tried.

Comment: got it, thanks sir, i'll migrate it if i don't get answers to superuser and I'll change the title to "is it possible to install spotify on debian weezy?" and I'll what i did and say that my solution didn't work, maybe there is another way to install it, i want to let people give me any solution they might know about not just libssl, i think I can avoid xy problem